# Get max from dict.values() with the same key

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

I have this csv.file. Let's say I already used `DictReader` and now I have some list full of dicts, like `('name': 'Andrew'), ('points': 18)` etc.

```
name    points
Andrew  18
Kate    10
Jack    55
Andrew  31
Andrew  100
Jack    58
Andrew  34
Kate    22
Jack    5
Andrew  72
```

What I want to do is to return a key-value pair like `Andrew: (5, 100)`, where the value is:

1. how many times I've met this name in a list;
2. the max number for this name from the **points** table.

I have no problem with the first task, but can't find the solution
for the 2nd one. That's what I tried to do:

```
name_counter = defaultdict(int)
max_points = defaultdict(int)
for dictionary in list_from_csv:
    name_counter[dictionary['name']] += 1 #every time I meet the name, I add +1 to the value
    max_points[dictionary['name']] = ???
```

I was thinking just use `max(dictionary[points])`, but max should pick from the number of numbers, not just one. Maybe create a list, but not sure how. Any other ideas?

Would appreciate any help.

P.S. And after I have these 2 dicts, I will need to merge them, based on the key, but I hope it is not that hard.

Comment: What should the merged dict look like?

Comment: Google how to use the `groupby` function.  I think you'll be able to finish from there.

Comment: What you show is not a list full of dicts, and it's not even legal Python syntax for _anything_. Please give us a usable example input if you want us to show you how to transform that input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to work out what to do to `max_points[name]` each time you get a new value, right?

Let's pretend that, at each iteration, `max_points[name]` has already been correctly set to the highest value that you've seen so far. So, what do you need to do with the new value?

Simple: if `points` is bigger than the highest value you've seen so far, it's the new highest value; if not, the old highest value is the new highest value.

Which is exactly what `max` does. So:

```
max_points[dictionary['name']] = max(max_points[dictionary['name']], points)
```

Now we just need to verify that assumption was correct.

- Since you're using `defaultdict(int)`, it always starts at 0. If you can have negative scores, that's already wrong, but otherwise, it's correct—the highest score you've seen so far, for anyone, is 0.
- At each step, if it was correct at the previous step, it's correct after the next step, because that's what `max` does.
- So, by induction, it's correct at the end.

---

As a side note, instead of repeating `dictionary['name']` over and over, it might look nicer like this:

```
for dictionary in list_from_csv:
    name = dictionary['name']
    name_counter[name] += 1
    max_points[name] = max(max_points[name], points)
```

Comment: My ow my, thank you!:) That was a really GOOD answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
data = [{'name': 'Andrew', 'points': 18}, {'name': 'Kate', 'points': 10}, {'name': 'Jack', 'points': 55}, {'name': 'Andrew', 'points': 31}, {'name': 'Andrew', 'points': 100}, {'name': 'Jack', 'points': 58}, {'name': 'Andrew', 'points': 34}, {'name': 'Kate', 'points': 22}, {'name': 'Jack', 'points': 5}, {'name': 'Andrew', 'points': 72}]
grouped_data = [[a, list(b)] for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(data, key=lambda x:x['name']), key=lambda x:x['name'])]
final_data = [{a:(len(b), max(b, key=lambda x:x['points'])['points'])} for a, b in grouped_data]
```

Output:

```
[{'Andrew': (5, 100)}, {'Jack': (3, 58)}, {'Kate': (2, 22)}]
```

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, here's the 3rd party Pandas one-liner:

```
res = df.groupby('name')['points'].agg(['size', 'max'])
```

**Result**

```
print(res)

        size  max
name             
Andrew     5  100
Jack       3   58
Kate       2   22
```

**Setup**

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

mystr = StringIO("""name    points
Andrew  18
Kate    10
Jack    55
Andrew  31
Andrew  100
Jack    58
Andrew  34
Kate    22
Jack    5
Andrew  72""")

df = pd.read_csv(mystr, delim_whitespace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution without using any extra import other than csv.

I've used your sample data as a csv file. I've read the content and created a list of tuples of (name, points)

```
import csv
list_of_tuples = []

with open('f1.csv', newline='') as csv_file:
    dict_of_csv = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for item in dict_of_csv:
        list_of_tuples.append((item['name'], item['points']))
```

The list_of_tuples looks like this

```
[('Andrew', '18'), ('Kate', '10'), ('Jack', '55'), ('Andrew', '31'), ('Andrew', '100'), ('Jack', '58'), ('Andrew', '34'), ('Kate', '22'), ('Jack', '5'), ('Andrew', '72')]
```

The result_dict stores data in {key: (tuple_0, tuple_1), } format
like

```
{ name: (name_count, max_points),
  name1: (name_count1, max_points1),
  ...
}
```

The values in a dictionary are identified with their `key`, which is the `name` in this case.
Like `dictionary['key']` so here `result_dict[name]`
The data in a tuple can be accessed as a normal list, like tuple[0] and tuple[1]
So here, it is `result_dict[name][0]` and `result_dict[name][1]`

```
result_dict = {}
for dict_item in list_of_tuples:
    name = dict_item[0]
    points = int(dict_item[1])
    if name in result_dict:
        name_count = result_dict[name][0]
        max_points = result_dict[name][1]
        result_dict[name] = (name_count + 1, points if max_points < points else max_points)
    else:
        # the name isn't in the dictionary, so we add the "name: (name_count, max_points)" to it
        result_dict[name] = (1, points)
```

The output is:

```
{'Andrew': (5, 100), 'Kate': (2, 22), 'Jack': (3, 58)}
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer!